# Iterating through a HashMap

Tags: search, iterator, hashmap, loops

Okay so i'm currently working on a searching method, the terms searched are ran through the database and the matching products are added to a hashMap with 2 Integer fields.

then after the hashmap is made, the items are to be shown, however i'm having trouble getting the hashmap to print out the details

here's my code

```
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> bankSearch = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

and the use

```
    Iterator it = bankSearch.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HashMap.Entry pairs = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        if (bankItemsN[i] > 254) {
            outStream.writeByte(255);
            outStream.writeDWord_v2(pairs.getValue());
        } else {
            outStream.writeByte(pairs.getValue()); // amount
        }
        if (bankItemsN[i] < 1) {
            bankItems[i] = 0;
        }
        outStream.writeWordBigEndianA(pairs.getKey()); // itemID
    }
```

current errors

```
.\src\client.java:75: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Iterator
location: class client
                Iterator it = bankSearch.entrySet().iterator();
                ^
.\src\client.java:77: java.util.HashMap.Entry is not public in java.util.HashMap
; cannot be accessed from outside package
                        HashMap.Entry pairs = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
                               ^
.\src\client.java:77: java.util.HashMap.Entry is not public in java.util.HashMap
; cannot be accessed from outside package
                        HashMap.Entry pairs = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
                                                      ^
3 errors
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What Java compiler are you using?  Also, is there a particular reason you are not using Java generics?

Answer (score 10):

The errors you are getting are due to:

- You did not import `java.util.Iterator`
- `HashMap.Entry` is a private inner class.  You should use `Map.Entry`

Also you should, as templatetypedef says, use the generic version of Iterator, or use a for-each construct.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is some actual code, demonstrating both approaches:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        m.put("One", 1);
        m.put("Two", 2);
        m.put("Three", 3);

        // Using a for-each
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " => " + e.getValue());
        }

        // Using an iterator
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = m.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>)it.next();
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " => " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the generic version of the iterator?
also,
package Map does not exist
Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

Comment: @Travis I added code to my answer, showing both approaches.  HTH.