# Loop through a hashmap using entrySet

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashMap in its own class in a different file.

```
public class className {

private HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

}
```

I want to loop through the hashMap and get the key if I pass it the value.  I am having trouble with the entrySet as I have been reading the following question.  [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007513/iterating-through-a-hashmap)

My Code for the for each loop is:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : className.entrySet()){


}
```

The className is the name of the class that contains my hashMap and I get the error:

> Cannot find symbol

I am guessing it is something to do with not having a method for entrySet but I'm not sure as the question I linked to above doesn't mention this.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Should you be getting the `entrySet` from your class containing the `HashMap` or from the `HashMap` itself?

Comment: if your object c of the class car has an Engine can you call the method of the engine in the c object directly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myMap` is on another `class` and it's `private` then you need a `public getter method` like below.

```
    public class className {

    private HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public Map getMyMap()
    {
       return myMap;
    }

}




for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : objectOfClassName.getMyMap().entrySet()){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the name of the Hashmap. Not the classname

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()){


}
```

Comment: sorry edited my question - its in a different file and the hashMap is private

Comment: @Silentbob then you need to craete a getter method for that hashMap

Comment: @Silentbob in that case you need a `public getter method` for `myap`

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your `myMap` entries set:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
  // do something with the entry
}
```